# Show images from hash tag on instagram

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

We are building an app where we would like to show images from Instagram from a specific hash-tag - because of the new API restrictions this is not possible.

Instagram mention that one should find a third party provider to provide such service - I can't find any - is there somebody who knows what possibilites there are?

Answer (score -1):

I found that Zapier can do this for you:

https://zapier.com/zapbook/instagram/

Free version has some limitations in the number of "Zaps" (= executions) of the script, but it may be enough, or you can switch to a paid plan.

Destination can be almost anything (for example a Firebase db or a Dropbox folder)